# Scheme - have a function return a value from another function for each member of a list

Tags: function, return, scheme

I am trying to write a function that returns a value for each element of a list but algebraic operation will be implemented on another funtcion. This is my first step:

> (define (base list another-fun)
>   ;every member of the list will be
>   send to enother-fun and all return as a value  )
>
> (define (funk a)     (lambda (c)   (* a c)
>       ))
>
> (define (funkc a)   (lambda (c)   (- a c)
>       ))

Here's my input:

> (define base '(1 2 3 4 5) (funk 2)) => (1 2 3 4 5 6) not '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
>
> (define base '(1 2 3 4 5) (funkc 1)) => (1 2 3 4 5 6) not '(0 1 2 3 4 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you're trying to implement is called [`map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), and it's a standard built-in procedure in Scheme. Try this:

```
(define (funk a)
  (lambda (c) (* a c)))

(define (funkc a)
  (lambda (c) (- a c)))

(map (funk 2) '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(2 4 6 8 10)

(map (funkc 1) '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(0 -1 -2 -3 -4)
```

Here's a [link](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_idx_1666) to the SICP book, explaining how to implement your own version of `map` in case you want to write it from scratch.

Comment: This answer could be improved with a short explanation of the implementation of `map`.

Comment: @IstvanChung that's referenced in the link, I don't see the point in "improving" SICP's explanation.

Comment: Well, that part of the answer is link-only, and doesn't have any value without the link, so for all the other reasons that link-only answers are bad, link-only *sections* can be improved. Also, it's not clear to me that the function requested is in fact `map`.